# Setting "toolbar" property of a nestedList

Tags: sencha-touch, nested-lists

I'm new to Sencha Touch 1. I'd like to add more items to the default NestedList toolbar, but I can't find a working example of using "toolbar" property.

From [Sencha Docs](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/1-1/#!/api/Ext.NestedList-property-toolbar):

```
toolbar : Object
Ext.Toolbar shared across each of the lists. This will only exist when useToolbar is true which is the default.
```

The only way I managed to do this is using initComponent method when creating the NestedList, but I feel like I'm reinventing the wheel...

```
var myNestedList= new Ext.NestedList({
    fullscreen: true,
    title: 'myTitle',
    useToolbar: true,
    store: myStore,
    initComponent : function() {
            ...
            }
```

...modifying this section

```
if (this.useToolbar) {
    // Add the back button
    this.backButton = new Ext.Button({
        text: this.backText,
        ui: 'back',
        handler: this.onBackTap,
        scope: this,
        // First stack doesn't show back
        hidden: true
    });

    // MY ADDED CODE
    var buttonsSpec = [
        { xtype: 'spacer' },
        { xtype: 'searchfield', placeHolder: 'Search', name: 'search' }
    ];
            // END MY ADDED CODE


    //this.searchButton.addListener('action', searchHandler);
    if (!this.toolbar || !this.toolbar.isComponent) {

                 /**
         * @cfg {Object} toolbar
         * Configuration for the Ext.Toolbar that is created within the Ext.NestedList.
         */
        this.toolbar = Ext.apply({}, this.toolbar || {}, {
            dock: 'top',
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            ui: 'light',
            title: title,
            items: [buttonsSpec] //MY ADDED CODE, WAS items: []
        });

        this.toolbar.items.unshift(this.backButton);
        this.toolbar = new Ext.Toolbar(this.toolbar);

        this.dockedItems = this.dockedItems || [];
        this.dockedItems.push(this.toolbar);
    } else {
        this.toolbar.insert(0, this.backButton);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not your search scope but may be an alternative solution.

Create your own toolbar and put it on top of the page and disable nested lists toolbar.

```
useToolbar:false,
```

and for back button handler; this method helps you;

```
nestedlist.onBackTap();
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: thanks ykartal, I had already considered your solution but I'm interested in the proper use of "toolbar" property